# Display a PDF in content page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have a Menu Item  "Manual". On clicking the Menu Item , it should open the PDF in content place holder. Here is how my ASPX page looks like

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"   Runat="Server">
 <embed id="srcfile" src="Manual/User Manual.pdf" width="980" height="1000" type='application/pdf' runat="server"></embed>
</asp:Content>
```

File displays correctly as I am expecting

Now the problem is embed tag is supported. Could someone help me in finding the fix.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: What is your target schema for markup validation? HTML 4, XHTML or HTML 5?

Comment: I think its XHTML, bcoz all my ASPX pages has Doc type at the top

Answer (score 0):

The `embed` HTML element is not part of the HTML 4 and XHTML specifications, but it is part of the HTML 5 specification.

So your choices are:

1. Switch to HTML 5 in your Visual Studio master page markup and then Visual Studio will no longer complain about an unsupported tag.
2. Use the `object` HTML element instead.
3. Ignore the Visual Studio warning and roll with what is working when you run the application.

Comment: My question is not able the File. Its about embed tag. There are no issues in opening the File. But Embed tag is not supported is what I see when opened in design mode